# Vis-timeline 7 and Angular 11

Tags: angular, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I've been using vis-timeline 6.5.2 successfully with Angular for some time.

In my package.json dependencies, I have `"vis-timeline": "^6.5.2"`

In my typescript files, I have `import { Timeline, DataSet } from 'vis-timeline';`

Everything works.

Now, I am trying to upgrade to version 7.4.7.  I changed the version in package.json and ran `npm install`.

First, my import statements break with

```
Module '"../../../../node_modules/vis-timeline/declarations"' declares 'DataSet' locally, but it is not exported
```

I can fix this by changing the imports to `import { Timeline, DataSet } from 'vis-timeline/standalone';`, but I have no idea if this is the correct thing to do.

When I try to run the project with `ng s` I get these errors:

```
Error: ./node_modules/vis-timeline/peer/umd/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js  
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vis-data/peer/umd/vis-data.js' in 'C:\Users\Ken\workspace\hatch-tools\node_modules\vis-timeline\peer\umd'
```

and also

```
Error: ./node_modules/vis-timeline/peer/umd/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'moment' in 'C:\Users\Ken\workspace\hatch-tools\node_modules\vis-timeline\peer\umd'
```

If I add `moment` and `vis-data` to my package.json I get yet more obscure errors.

Any advice on how to get vis-timeline 7 working in Angular?

I am on Angular 11.2.8 and Node 14.16.1.

Answer (score 3):

I just started using vis-timeline recently and did the obvious of trying to use the latest version, then installing all of the required peer dependencies. Once I got it compiling I ran into runtime issues like 'Cannot read property 'get' of undefined whenever I clicked an editable event (note: this *was* happening on the [examples](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/) page a couple of days ago as well, but isn't now)

After searching around, I found this post and downgraded the version to 6.5.2.  I then realized that there's a security risk in 6.5.2 [link](https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline/pull/840).

Going back in to it, I dug around and found the version (7.4.4) where they addressed said security issue. This version doesn't have the same issues I mentioned earlier at run time.

I used the following successfully on an Angular 11.2.8 project:

package.json

```
"vis-timeline": "7.4.4",
"@egjs/hammerjs": "2.0.17",
"keycharm": "0.4.0",
"moment": "2.29.1",
"propagating-hammerjs": "2.0.1",
"uuid": "7.0.3",
"vis-data": "7.1.2",
"vis-util": "4.3.4",
"xss": "1.0.8",
```

component:

```
   import { DataSet } from 'vis-data/esnext';
   import { Timeline } from 'vis-timeline/esnext';
```

(you could also import both from 'vis-timeline/standalone' but we use webpack, so the esnext option was better for our application - [ref](https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline#builds))

Comment: I managed to have VIS timeline running under Angular 12 using the same tricks as above.
Beware newest version of visjs (7.4.8) doesn't work for me and throws the same error.
Keep the versions of @Eric in your package.json

Comment: Thanks for the info guys I figured out it does work using Angular 12 and latest vis-timeline. demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uhmdx2

Comment: Did some troubleshooting and managed to make it work for V13 with latest vis-timeline. Checkout this repo: https://github.com/benjaminv/angular-vis-timeline

Answer (score 1):

vis-[data|timeline] 7 and Angular 16 here, what worked for me:

- `npm i vis-data vis-timeline` (As of this writing vis-data: ^7.1.7 and vis-timeline: ^7.7.2)
- On `styles.scss`: `@import "vis-timeline/dist/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css";`
- On the componnent's HTML template: `... < div id="blah"></div> ...`
- On the component:

```js
    import { DataSet } from 'vis-data';
    import {
      DataGroup,
      DataItem,
      Timeline,
      TimelineOptions,
      TimelineOptionsTemplateFunction,
      TimelineTooltipOption,
    } from 'vis-timeline';
    import { DateType } from 'vis-timeline/types';
    
    ...
    
    export class BlahComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

      // Added here to exemplify how to use it
      const groupsArray: DataGroup[] = [];
      const itemsArray: DataItem[] = [];
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.timeline = new Timeline(
          this._renderer.selectRootElement('blah'),
          items: new DataSet(itemsArray), // read vis-timeline docs on how to set this up
          groups: new DataSet(groupsArray), // read vis-timeline docs on how to set this up
          options, // read vis-timeline docs on how to set this up
        );
     
     ...
```

- On the component's SCSS: I'm using `::ng-deep` to override the CSS from  vis-timeline

---

Getting an Angular component to render "inside" a vis-timeline template also took some gymnastics:

- I have a prefix component on my project
- I want to render it in the `groupTemplate`

```js
visTimelineOptions = {
 ...
 groupTemplate: this.generateGroupTemplateClosure(groupToPrefixMap)
}

...

private generateGroupTemplateClosure(
    groupToPrefixMap: Map<string, Prefix>
  ): TimelineOptionsTemplateFunction {
    return (group: DataGroup) => {
      // set up an entry in the DOM
      const container = document.createElement('div');

      // CDK magic
      const componentRef = new DomPortalOutlet(
        container,
        this.componentFactoryResolver,
        this.appRef
      ).attach(new ComponentPortal(PrefixComponent));

      // pass values to the @Input-marked params
      componentRef.setInput(
        'prefix',
        groupToPrefixMap.get(group.id as string)!
      );
      componentRef.setInput('text', group.content as string);

      return container;
    };
  }
```

Comment: I wanted to thank you for the portal example, that's unlocked something for me that I couldn't fathom before!

Answer (score 0):

I was tasked to firing up a new timeline today as well and I am seeing the same issues.  Started a bare bones angular project from scratch to isolate everything and had to run the 'npm i' on vis-data, vis-util and moment which all came in before just by installing the timeline.  Even after installing those I am getting an error for XSS namespace and hammerJs (did a 'npm i hammerjs' and still get the error).  I had to revert to the same version as you where previously using.  This build will need to be fixed before it can be used.